# How to create layers with LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I've been trying to port my previous game from C# to Java. I'm wondering how I can create graphics layers that I can draw tiles on.

Comment: I thought about creating an array of tile grids, but that didn't seem to work out.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you'd like to do (screenshot?). OpenGL doesn't really have any concept of a 'layer'.

Comment: I'm creating a tile-based game and I wanted to create layers so I can draw on top of other layers. Ex: Draw a tree on the upper layer and have grass on the layer below it.

Comment: Well I managed to draw a single tile over others, but I want to store my array of tiles(TileGrid) in an array of tile grids(TileLayer)..or am I approaching this wrong? Should the TileGrid contain layers?

Comment: You don't really have discrete layers, you just have a depth buffer. In 2D, you just assign each triangle that you draw a Z-depth. Triangles with greater depth are occluded by those with lesser depth. If you wanted to think in layers, you could just have lowest layer have depth 10, next layer depth 9, next 8, etc. This should be covered in any rudimentary OpenGL tutorial, I suggest you try to read some beginner's guides.

Comment: "that didn't seem to work out." *How* didn't it "work out?" What problem did you have? That's what you should be asking about, where the bug in your actual code is.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the depth buffer, the color buffer and the stencil buffer you can use Frame Buffer Object(FBO) http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html.

It can be used as a drawing destination, for example to make a mirror you first render the mirror point of view onto some temporary texture and then you render the mirror with this texture, same way you can make a texture for each layer so you can draw exactly on the layer you need and in the end render all the layers in different heights (or what you want to do with them).

Or like Tim commented simply when you want to draw something on layer 'n' you render it on height z=n but that way you wont have a physical layer image but all of them combined, so if you need them for some after image processing (special effects on different layers) or saving them as images you should use FBO. But in some cases you can just apply different shaders when drawing on different layer.

FBO is harder to use but a lot powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

For me works best (in 2D games):

- Z-Buffer: first setup Z-buffer and when you draw you define each time a Z value and that's it (but fails at half transparent objects)
- knowing the draw order: draw the low layer first, top layer last (slower than z-Buffer)